# Load video on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I written some PHP code to load a video on `mouseenter` in a photo, but I would like to make the `src` of the video remain unknown and load only on `mouseenter`, to make the page lighter.

So many other websites do it, but I do not know if they do it with jQuery.

```
<video src="<?php the_field("video_url"); ?>"></video>
```

Comment: Firstly note that what you're trying to achieve has nothing to do with PHP, so I removed it from the title and tags. Secondly, the event you mention is `mouseenter` so I also changed the reference to `mouseleave` in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve.

Upon hovering over the image, I use `.replaceWith()` method to replace the image with a video with the current markup

- `<video src='https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4' autoplay></video>`

Notice `autoplay` inside of it, this will play the video immediately.

Here's what I've done:

---

```js
$('img').mouseenter(function(e) {
  $(this).replaceWith("<video src='https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4' autoplay></video>");
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

video {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg" alt="Big Buck Bunny">
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language, so it will have no awareness of client-side interactions like `mouseenter`. PHP is already done with the page before it makes it to the browser. So this will be the domain of JavaScript (or jQuery if you prefer).

An example using vanilla JavaScript. You can echo in script blocks just the same as html.

```css
#vid_container{
width:300px;
min-height:150px;

background:#333;
}
video{
opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id='vid_container'><!-- so we don't show the broken video add a container -->
  <video id='vid' controls src="" width="300"></video>
</div>
<script>
  var videoURL = "<?php echo the_field('video_url'); ?>";//IDK what the_field does, but point being this is where you would put the video url
  videoURL = "https://archive.org/download/ElephantsDream/ed_1024_512kb.mp4";//so the demo will work. remove this line
  var vidContainer = document.getElementById('vid_container');
  vidContainer.addEventListener('mouseenter', function fireOnce(){
    var vid = vidContainer.children[0];
    vid.style.opacity = 1;
    vid.src = videoURL;
    vidContainer.removeEventListener('mouseenter', fireOnce);//this is provided you don't want to change the video multiple times (for every mouseenter event
  });
</script>
```